# Update only the top 1 row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below:

[image]

As You see, the column `officebudge` updated with value for all individual offices. i want the `update` happen only top 1 office 
like below:

[image]

any suggesion to update the top 1 record?
I used below code. but it updates all the office entries:

```
UPDATE budget
  SET   officebudge = ISNULL(ProjectedReturnCount,0)
  FROM analyticsdata
  join
  (
  select   ofc.officeid,ofc.week,
  max(ISNULL(ofc.ProjectedReturnCount,0)) ProjectedReturnCount
  from
  BudgetOffice ofc
  INNER JOIN budget anal
  on ofc.OfficeID = anal.OfficeID
  and ofc.Week      = anal.week
  and ofc.RowStatus = 'a' 
  group by ofc.OfficeID,ofc.week
  )z
  on (z.officeid = budget.OfficeID
  and z.Week    = budget .week )
```

thanks for the help.  I have attached a sql fiddle to demonstrate this.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2b32/7

Comment: i did same thing very recently using row_number.since you hv provided image,so it will take long to prepare everything.if you can provide sample data then i can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CTE like this (I have used only few of your provided columns)

```
;With cte As
(Select *, Row_Number() Over(Partition By OfficeID order by RowID) As rn
From Employee)

update cte set OfficeBudge = 0 where rn>1

select * from Employee
```

Find the attached fiddle
**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a201/1)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But i want the result table need to be updated not the cte.

Comment: @bmsqldev I have used CTE.You can see your result has been updated.

Comment: Thanks that  work's for me. Actually i Weren't aware that  updating cte updating table too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that you want using cte (Common Table Expression)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Take a look at item B of the link above.